# Completing Promises after runs/waitsFor in Jasmine 1.3

Tags: javascript, jasmine, jasmine-node

I'm using jasmine-node 1.14.5, which underneath uses jasmine 1.3, and I'm having issues getting `runs/waitFor` to work properly with Promises.

In certain tests, I'd like to `runs/waitFor` to wait for a particular condition to happen, and when it occurs, fulfil a Promise that I return back. However, the moment I attempt to construct a Promise passing in the `function(success, fail)` parameter, none of the code inside the `runs/waitFor` gets called. However, if the Promise is resolved directly, it works. Any idea the former option does not work?

To give some examples, the following works fine:

```js
  it("should support async execution of test preparation and expectations", function(done) {
    var p = Promise.resolve("boo")
      .then(function() {
        var p2 = Promise.resolve("whatever");

        runs(function() {
          flag = false;
          value = 0;
          intId = setInterval(function() {
            console.log(value);
            if (++value == 3) { clearInterval(intId); flag = true; }
          }, 500);
        });

        waitsFor(function() {
          return flag;
        }, "The Value should be incremented", 5000);

        runs(function() {
          expect(value).toEqual(3);
        });

        return p2;
      });
    p.then(function() {
      done();
    }).catch(function(err) {
      done(err);
    });
  });
```

But on the other hand, this does not work because although `runs/waitsFor` are called without problems, the callbacks inside do not:

```js
  it("should support async execution of test preparation and expectations", function(done) {
    var p = Promise.resolve("boo")
      .then(function() {
        return new Promise(function (fulfil, reject) {
          runs(function () {
            flag = false;
            value = 0;
            intId = setInterval(function () {
              console.log(value);
              if (++value == 3) {
                clearInterval(intId);
                flag = true;
              }
            }, 500);
          });

          waitsFor(function () {
            return flag;
          }, "The Value should be incremented", 5000);

          runs(function () {
            expect(value).toEqual(3);
            fulfil();
          });
        });
      });
    p.then(function() {
      done();
    }).catch(function(err) {
      done(err);
    });
  });
```

I've also tried the following in the off chance but does not work either, it behaves the same way as the previous example:

```js
  it("should support async execution of test preparation and expectations", function(done) {
    var p = Promise.resolve("boo")
      .then(function() {
        var outerFulfil;
        var outerReject;
        var p2 = new Promise(function(fulfil, reject) {
          outerFulfil = fulfil;
          outerReject = reject;
        });

        runs(function() {
          flag = false;
          value = 0;
          intId = setInterval(function() {
            console.log(value);
            if (++value == 3) { clearInterval(intId); flag = true; }
          }, 500);
        });

        waitsFor(function() {
          return flag;
        }, "The Value should be incremented", 5000);

        runs(function() {
          expect(value).toEqual(3);
          outerFulfil();
        });

        return p2;
      });
    p.then(function() {
      done();
    }).catch(function(err) {
      done(err);
    });
  });
```

Any idea how to solve it? Although the first example works, it does not behave the way I want because I only want the promise to be fulfilled once the assertions after the `waitsFor` have been carried out.

Cheers,
Galder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up ditching runs/waitsFor altogether, and instead do a time based recursive Promise loop, e.g.

```js
function waitUntil(expectF, cond, op) {
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  function done(actual) {
    return cond(actual)
      && new Date().getTime() < now + MAX_WAIT;
  }

  function loop(promise) {
    exports.sleepFor(100); // brief sleep

    // Simple recursive loop until condition has been met
    return promise
      .then(function(response) {
        return !done(response)
          ? loop(op())
          : response;
      })
      .catch(function() {
        return loop(op());
      });
  }

  return loop(op())
    .then(function(actual) {
      expectF(actual);
    });
}
```

`op` is an operation that returns a Promise.

For example, I wanted to wait until certain number of nodes have joined a cluster:

```js
function waitUntilView(expectNumMembers, nodeName) {
  return waitUntil(
    function(members) { expect(members.length).toEqual(expectNumMembers); },
    function(members) { return _.isEqual(expectNumMembers, members.length); },
    getClusterMembers(nodeName)
  );
}
```